# Transmission not down shifting

Tags: transmission

I have a 2005 Buick Rendezvous.  Traveling between 45-55mph and going up a slight hill the transmission will not downshift but it will make the engine stutter.  If I tap the brake, the transmission will downshift.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you checked the fluid level?

Comment: Fluid level is fine.  I actually replaced the fluid.